# Scroll to enter - But in other page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Splash Page and I need use 'scroll to enter' for go in home, but I need enter in other page. 
So, I use this code at moment for enter with click, it's possible implement this code with a scroll function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".page-splash-page").click(function(){
        window.location = "http://localhost:8888/solaris/it/work/"
    })
});
```

I have try this but doesn't work!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".page-splash-page").click(function(){
        window.location = "http://localhost:8888/solaris/it/work/"
    });
    $(".page-splash-page").scroll(function(){
        window.location = "http://localhost:8888/solaris/it/work/"
    });
});
```

Comment: To be clear, you want to click ".page-splash-page" and have that navigate to the "http://localhost:8888/solaris/it/work/" URL and have that page scroll?

Comment: @Enijar i want use both function for go in other page. Go by clic and go by scroll

Comment: Artur's answer should be the solution for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to listen to mousewheel you can do this:

```
$('.page-splash-page"').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
   window.location = "http://localhost:8888/solaris/it/work/"
});
```

Comment: Yes this it's what i want do but still not work. It's possible use scroll and not mousewheel?

Comment: Does the ".page-splash-page" element have a scrollbar? If not - try $(document).scroll(function(){window.location = "http://localhost:8888/solaris/it/work/"})

Comment: Doesn't have scroll, it's just a fix div with img and some text. With overflow: hidden. I have jet try what you write now. Me too was thinking was the true way. But don't work.I have try to put out overflow. But not work.

Comment: If mousewheel and document scroll are not the events you are looking for then what is the "scroll" you are talking about please?

Comment: It's correct, sorry. I need when mousewheel go from Splash Page to Home Page. Now this append only with i clic on window.

Comment: Arthur your code work good! thanks. Do you know way mousewheel is slowly to got to the link then click function ?